# The :hover effect does not work if the background color was previously specified in the styles

Tags: html, css

```css
ul li {
  background: blue;
}

ul li: hover {
  color: pink;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-inline text-center">
  <li class="list-inline-item" style="width: 80px;height: 30px;padding-top: 3px;background: blue;">GAMES</li>
  <li class="list-inline-item" style="width: 80px;height: 30px;padding-top: 3px;background: #929292;">ABOUT</li>
</ul>
```

After setting the color to blue in the first block, it is set, but the :hover action doesn't work. BUT when I remove `background: blue` from the first block, it works, how can I fix it?

P.S - text-color working

Comment: `ul li:hover { background: red !important; }`

Comment: please notice, there's an extra blank space here: `ul li: hover` it should be `ul li:hover`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're having an inline style for the background color.

You should remove the inline style or add an `!important` to your hover effect.

Answer (score 1):

I test your code. You should edit your CSS code and add `!important` like this :

```css
ul li:hover {
  color: pink;
  background: red !important;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-inline text-center">
  <li class="list-inline-item" style="width: 80px;height: 30px;padding-top: 3px;background: blue;">GAMES</li>
  <li class="list-inline-item" style="width: 80px;height: 30px;padding-top: 3px;background: #929292;">ABOUT</li>
</ul>
```